# Can PowerShell replace a case sensitive portion of text it found using -clike?

Tags: powershell, replace, case-sensitive

Let's say I have two addresses:

- 123 Newark Road Ne
- 987 Ne Netherland Avenue

I need to update the directional portion from Ne to NE. However, I don't want to update Newark to NEwark and the same for Netherland. I think I can find all the instances easy enough with this IF statement in a loop:

```
$testAddress = '123 Newark Road Ne'
if (($testAddress -clike '* Ne') -or ($testAddress -clike '* Ne *')){
   #code to replace Ne
}
```

But how do I go about replacing it? I can't use a -creplace '* Ne', '* NE'. Finding the index of '* Ne' just gives me -1 so I don't think I can do anything with that. I'm sure there's an easy concept that I'm just not coming across.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions to replace a certain part of your input with something which is not possible in the substitution operand in a regex expression by design (like uppercasing in .NET) by using a `MatchEvaluator`, which is constructed in PowerShell like a scriptblock.

With that MatchEvaluator you can manipulate the matched part like you want, hence you are not restricted to anything when it comes to manipulation.

Beginning with PowerShell 6 you can even use it directly with the `-replace` and `-creplace` operators.
PowerShell versions below 6 does not have this option, but it's still possible using the .NET Regex Replace Method `[regex]::Replace()` with a MatchEvaluator.

### PS 5.1

```
$textToReplace = 'Ne 123 Newark Road Ne', '123 Newark Road Ne', '987 Ne Netherland Avenue'

foreach ($text in $textToReplace) {
    # using a scriptblock as System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator
    # the param() part is mandatory. Everything that follows is the return for that particular match
    [regex]::Replace($text, '(?<!\w)Ne(?!\w)', { param($regexMatch) $regexMatch.Value.ToUpper() })
}
```

### PS 6+

```powershell
$textToReplace = 'Ne 123 Newark Road Ne', '123 Newark Road Ne', '987 Ne Netherland Avenue'

foreach ($text in $textToReplace) {
    $text -creplace '(?<!\w)Ne(?!\w)', { $_.Value.toUpper() }
}
```

### Regular Expression Pattern Explanation

The pattern `(?<!\w)Ne(?!\w)` matches all words `Ne` for which the preceding and following character is not a word character using a `negative lookbehind (?<!)` and `negative lookahead (?!)` group construct.

`\w` (Word) in `.NET` includes all **Unicode** characters of the following categories:
[MSFT: Character classes in regular expressions -> Word character: \w](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#word-character-w):

These include, but are not limited to:

- `a-z` and variants like `è`
- `A-Z` and variants like `À`
- `0-9`
- `_`
- *cyrillic characters*
- *chinese characters*
- ...

In short, `\w` captures **almost** all word characters which are represented in the Unicode character set.

## Resources

[MSFT: Replacement with a script block in PS6+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-with-a-script-block)

Answer (score 0):

```
@('123 Newark Road Ne'
'987 Ne Netherland Avenue')|foreach{
    switch -regex ($_)
    {
        'Ne$'{$_ -replace 'Ne$','NE'}
        ' Ne '{$_ -replace ' Ne ',' NE '}
        Default {$_}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use word boundaries around `Ne`:

```
'123 Newark Road Ne','987 Ne Netherland Avenue' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -cmatch '(\bNe\b)') { $_ -creplace '(\bNe\b)', $Matches[1].ToUpper() }
    else { $_ }
}
```

Output

```
123 Newark Road NE
987 NE Netherland Avenue
```